Transport equation with dirichlet boundaries counditions
my fellows mathematicians,
I have a question concerning the linear transport equation in a very simple case (1D with Dirichlet boundaries conditions)
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    & f : x \in [0,1], t \ge 0 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
    &\partial_t f + c \partial_x f=0 \\
    &f(t=0)=f_0 \\
    &f(x=0)=f(x=1)=0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
If we take $f_0$ as a centered gaussian, the result with periodic boundaries conditions is just a shift of the function. But if we add the Dirichlet boundaries, is the problem even well posed or it become ill-posed ?
Thank you so much for helping a noob and stupid physicist lost in the jungle of PDEs.

The problem is overdetermined, as you are imposing two boundary conditions (at $x=0$ and $x=1$) on a PDE that is first order in $x$.
